# How to use VBA to VLOOKUP across workbooks, sheet by sheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros, vlookup

my apologies in advance - I am relatively novice with VBA

I have a report generated daily, with several sheets (Let's say Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3). These sheets have tables where I track notes for each order line, and I would like to vlookup the notes from day to day.

The issue I am facing:  I need to be able to repeat this for Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3, pulling from the previous day's respective Sheet1, 2, 3, and repeat this day by day.

Is there a way for the vlookup to recognize my active sheet name, e.g. Sheet3, and look back at the prior day's workbook and pull from that Sheet3?

Is this something that can be done?

Thank you for any help

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this.  Unfortunately you are asking several questions in one post (whether you know it or not).  Stack Overflow is for more targeted questions.  I recommend that you attempt to record a macro that accomplishes what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi n8 thank you for the reply - I will edit my original post to reflect the specific problem I am trying to address

Comment: @n8. 
`Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
   
 Range("D2").Select
   
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
     
   "=VLOOKUP([@Column1],'[PLS DMD 
022416.xlsm]Sheet3'!C3:C4,2,FALSE)"
  
  Range("D3").Select`

This is what I am presently working with but this would only apply to pulling from Sheet3 onto the new 022516 Sheet3. This would also not allow me to repeat this the next day from (PLS DMD 022616) as it would not reference 022516, but still 022416

Comment: Are you going cell-by-cell?

Comment: @n8. I am trying to go sheet by sheet, the vlookup is supposed to populate downward for each line

Comment: By setting variables you can retrieve sheet names, etc.  so, `thisSheet = Activesheet.Name` will store the name of the sheet, which you can then use like `"=VLOOKUP([@Column1],'[PLS DMD 022416.xlsm]" & thisSheet  & "'!C3:C4,2,FALSE)"`

Comment: To be specific, are the notes always in the same column?  Are you trying to push old notes out to the right so you can keep new notes in the leftmost column?

Comment: You will also need a way to identify the "prior day workbook".  This is possible through logic, but you need to specify it somehow.  It's a bit beyond the novice skill set.  Perhaps having a control sheet where you can input the file name from which you want to retrieve the notes.

Comment: Thank you @n8. so I can use this to reference the older sheet, when I am looking at the newer sheet? I am not sure if this makes sense but, would the older sheet be the "active" sheet if the vlookup table array is in that sheet? I am not experienced with setting variables - I appreciate all your help so far. The notes will always be in the same column.

Comment: The active book will be the one you'll be importing notes into, in all probability.  To be clear, the sheet names are the same between the older and newer books, correct?

Comment: Yes, the sheet names will be consistent. Sheet 1 on 022416 will correspond to Sheet 1 on 022516 and Sheet 1 on 022616 every time. Same for Sheet 2, etc.

Comment: Do you have a template that imports the data every day?  Can we presume that if you make a sheet that contains variables and a trigger button then it will persist from day to day?

Comment: The data generated daily is pulled in from pivot tables - any sheet I create would have to be manually taken from day to day. I could possibly work with the workbook creator to put this sheet with trigger/variables on the daily report. Would that be necessary?

Comment: Not necessary, but it's an option.  The macro needs to be in a consistent location, and if it's not within the workbook that pulls in the data, then you have to have a way to identify both workbooks.  Does the report dump to a particular folder every day?

Comment: Hi @n8. in theory since the macro needs a consistent location could I keep it on a sheet and move it to the book every day? Or put it on a sheet that generates the report? I'm still having trouble setting up these variables you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Before you get where you are trying to go you need a consistent starting point.  I would create a new workbook and hold your logic there.  You don't need your macro to be in the workbook that your data is.

Like this:
[image]

Using named ranges is best in case you want to change the look of your control workbook, and you can create formulas for the file names so that they default to your current day and prior workday.

The code would launch both workbooks.  Hopefully this is a valid starting point for you and gives you an idea how to proceed.

```
Sub mergeThese()

    path_New = Range("path_New")
    path_Old = Range("path_Old")
    file_New = Range("file_New")
    file_Old = Range("file_Old")

    Workbooks.Open path_Old & file_Old
    Workbooks.Open path_New & file_New

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @n8. this is a great place for me to work off of - I want to express again my gratitude!

Comment: Let me know if you run into problems.  And give me an up-vote!  I like points.